# Optimizing Requests parsing a 50 mil rows MySQL table

Tags: mysql, query-optimization

I have a request that I need to process multiple time during specific time frames, my implementation is working, but my user base is growing everyday and the CPU load of my database and the time taken to execute the query is getting bigger everyday

Here is the request:

```
SELECT bill.* FROM billing bill
            INNER JOIN subscriber s ON (s.subscriber_id = bill.subscriber_id) 
            INNER JOIN subscription sub ON(s.subscriber_id = sub.subscriber_id)
            WHERE s.status = 'C' 
            AND bill.subscription_id = sub.subscription_id                      
            AND sub.renewable = 1
            AND (hour(sub.created_at) > 1 AND hour(sub.created_at) < 5 )
            AND sub.store = 'BizaoStore'
            AND (sub.purchase_token = 'myservice' or sub.purchase_token = 'myservice_wait' ) 
            AND bill.billing_date > '2022-12-31 07:00:00' AND bill.billing_date < '2023-01-01 10:00:00'
            AND (bill.billing_value = 'not_ok bizao_tobe' or bill.billing_value =  'not_ok BILL010 2' or bill.billing_value =  'not_ok BILL010' or bill.billing_value = 'not_ok BILL010 3')
            AND (SELECT MAX(bill2.billing_date)
                FROM billing bill2
                WHERE bill2.subscriber_id = bill.subscriber_id
                AND bill2.subscription_id = bill.subscription_id 
                AND bill2.billing_value = 'not_ok bizao_tobe') 
            = bill.billing_date order by sub.created_at DESC LIMIT 300;
```

This request is executed in two different servers, each serve handle a specific service.
In each server, the request runs 8 times per minut (for around 3 hours) and
each of the 8 times has this line with different hours:

```
AND (hour(sub.created_at) >  1 AND hour(sub.created_at) < 5 )
```

I did this so I can split my user base in 8 and process the requests more efficiently.
Also I need to only handle 300 users at a time because the third party server I have to call for each user is not very stable and can sometime take very long to respond

The billing tables counts around 50.000.000 entries, here is the schema of the columns and indexes:

[image]

Subscriber table is around 2.000.000, columns scheme and indexes:
[image]

And finally subscription table, 2.500.000 rows, scheme and indexes:
[image]

As a few more infos, I noticed during my tests for optimisation that if I add in my request the fact that I want datas with a "billing_id" over a specific ID, it will run very fast. Basically I think whats taking the most time is parsing the 50.000.000 lines tables.

I did (or at least I tried) to optimize my request with time to be more efficient, but as of now I'm a little bit stuck with it.

Mysql version is 5.7.38

Thanks for your help

Comment: Careful with date ranges: You have `AND bill.billing_date > '2022-12-31 07:00:00' AND bill.billing_date < '2023-01-01 10:00:00'` but you might want to use `>=` in the first part like this `AND bill.billing_date >= '2022-12-31 07:00:00' AND bill.billing_date < '2023-01-01 10:00:00'`

Comment: Updated my code accordingly ! Thanks for this

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I see a few opportunities to speed up this query. (Reference: Markus Winand's https://use-the-index-luke.com/ e-book.)

1. Replace your [correlated subquery](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/correlated-subqueries.html) (`SELECT MAX(bill2.billing_date)...`) with an independent subquery.
2. Try to make all your `WHERE` clauses [sargable](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sargable) -- able to exploit indexes.
3. Add appropriate indexes.

**Independent subquery** Obtain latest billing date for each subscriber / subscription like this. This query need only run once, whereas the correlated subquery you have runs many times.

```sql
      SELECT MAX(billing_date) billing_date,
             subscriber_id,
             subscription_id
        FROM billing
       WHERE billing_value = 'not_ok bizao_tobe'
       GROUP BY subscriber_id, subscription_id
```

Use this index to speed up the subquery. This index allows the subquery to be satisfied with an almost miraculously fast [loose index scan](https://dev.mysql.com/blog-archive/what-is-the-scanning-variant-of-a-loose-index-scan/).

```sql
CREATE INDEX value_subscriber_subscription_date ON billing
   (billing_value, subscriber_id, subscription_id, billing_date DESC);
```

Then rewrite your overall query like this to use it. I have rewritten a few other things here as well to improve readability: mostly changing `col = a OR col = b OR col = c` to `col IN (a,b,c)`. I also changed the order of some WHERE clauses, again for readability. The order of WHERE clauses doesn't matter to performance.

```sql
SELECT bill.* 
  FROM billing bill
  JOIN subscriber s ON s.subscriber_id = bill.subscriber_id 
  JOIN subscription sub   ON s.subscriber_id = sub.subscriber_id
                         AND bill.subscription_id = sub.subscription_id
  JOIN (
      SELECT MAX(billing_date) billing_date,
             subscriber_id,
             subscription_id
        FROM billing
       WHERE billing_value = 'not_ok bizao_tobe'
       GROUP BY subscriber_id, subscription_id
       ) latest   ON bill.subscriber_id = latest.subscriber_id
                 AND bill.subscription_id = latest.subscription_id 
                 AND bill.billing_date = latest.billing_date                 
 WHERE s.status = 'C' 
   AND (hour(sub.created_at) > 1 AND hour(sub.created_at) < 5 )
   AND sub.renewable = 1
   AND sub.store = 'BizaoStore'
   AND sub.purchase_token IN ('myservice', 'myservice_wait' ) 
   AND bill.billing_value IN (
      'not_ok bizao_tobe', 'not_ok BILL010 2', 
      'not_ok BILL010', 'not_ok BILL010 3')
   AND bill.billing_date > '2022-12-31 07:00:00' 
   AND bill.billing_date < '2023-01-01 10:00:00'
 ORDER BY sub.created_at DESC
 LIMIT 300;
```

**Sargability** Your segmenting of your user base by hours of the day means you need this clause, as you pointed out.

```sql
AND (HOUR(sub.created_at) >  1 AND HOUR(sub.created_at) < 5 )
```

This clause applies the HOUR() function to every eligible row so it has to scan through the rows looking at them all. Slow. Add a [virtual column](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/create-table-generated-columns.html) called `created_hour` to your `subscription` table. We'll put an index on the column in a moment.

```sql
ALTER TABLE subscription 
     ADD COLUMN created_hour TINYINT 
     GENERATED ALWAYS AS (HOUR(created_at)) VIRTUAL;
```

Then start using the virtual column to segment your users.

```sql
AND (sub.created_hour >  1 AND sub.created_hour < 5)
```

**Indexes** Compound (multicolumn) indexes are the way to speed up complex queries like yours. The order of columns matters in indexes. The columns with equality matches go first, then a column with a range match.

First, let's put a compound index on your `subscription` table that matches the requirements of your query. We'll index our new virtual column in the process. This lets the query planner find your batches efficiently.

The last column in this index is `created_at`. That speeds up your `ORDER BY ... LIMIT` operation.

```sql
CREATE INDEX renewable_store_token_hour_created 
     ON subscription (renewable, store, purchase_token,
                      created_hour, created_at);
```

Next, let's look at how you use `billing` in your main query. (We already added an index to help the subquery). You match for equality on `billing_value` and then by a date range on `billing_date`. So you need this index.

```sql
CREATE INDEX value_date ON billing (billing_value, billing_date);
```

You already have the index you need on `subscriber`.

Comment: thank you very much for this detailed answer, I've started a fire with just adding indexes to billing_date, and subscription.created_at as suggested  by Musa Haidari, so time for me to extinguish it and I'll try your recommandations and update accordingly!

Comment: Sometimes sorting out these performance problems is best done by experimenting on a copy of your tables. For best results, include all data from your production database, and use *exactly* the same version of your MySQL software on the copy. This will probably help your situation. It doesn't help much when you're trying to deal with multiuser contention, but that's not the situation here (at least if it is you didn't mention it.)

Comment: I've duplicated my environement with the exact same datas and been able to add first two changes you suggested, as of now it seems to work very well but I need to wait an heavy load which will be coming later on today. Will definitely update the topic here. 
I've encountered an error in the last change while creating the renewable_store_token_hour_created index which is:
"BLOB/TEXT column 'purchase_token' used in key specification without a key length. "From what I understand it's because my purchase_token field is a TEXT field

Comment: I missed that your `purchase_token` column, and some other columns, are `TEXT`. You will have a *much* easier time optimizing if you can change the definition of your `TEXT` columns to something like `VARCHAR(128)`.  Change as many of them as you can. Definitely change the ones appearing in WHERE or ON clauses.

Comment: May as well make the index for the derived table "covering": 
 `INDEX((billing_value, billing_date, subscriber_id, subscription_id)`

Comment: I've been able to change two fields to VARCHAR and successfuly applied the renewable_store_token_hour_created and value_date  indexes. I will check MYSQL slow query logs and update the post later on today. Rick James could you explain on the drived table "covering" please ? I understand that the order of columns is important, but I'm not sure which one I should or should not add

Answer (score 2):

I think there could be some rooms for improvement, some are easier to do some takes more efforts:

1. You mentioned you tried to improve the performance with limiting the time, which I assume mean `AND (hour(sub.created_at) >  1 AND hour(sub.created_at) < 5 )`, however `sub.created_at` does not have an index. It is a good idea `created_at` and `updated_at` columns always have indexes on in the database.
2. Additionally you can add an index on `bill.billing_date`
3. There is a sub-query finding `MAX(bill2.billing_date)`. This can be a bottleneck too, as this subquery needs to run for each row of the previous stage of execution (you can check that with `explain` query). Depending on your condition you can store that max field somewhere, like a column in database, cache, etc. and keep updating it every time the underlying table's values change. You can do it with database triggers (which some people consider it anti pattern) or use the transaction inside your code.
4. You can run the query against a replica and do not care if it takes a lot of time.

Having all said, the first point might improve the performance a lot, and hence making the rest not necessary

Comment: Not sure if I was quite clear, but the optimization with hour of subscription date creation was used to split my user base in 8 pools of users. With this i'm sure that the 8 processes running at the same timestamps will not target the same users. I will add both recommended indexes as a first move and letting you know if it works.
Regarding the 3. point, the max value can change a few times each days, but I'll dig into it too, regarding the last point, I do care the time taken to execute all the request as it needs to be all processed in a shortest amount of time possible !

Comment: I see the point of sharding into 8 pools, but still it needs a full scan, as it does not have an index, so it should probably be a bottleneck here